# What does it means 100v, 10A ,100W darlington transistor?

Tags: power, transistors, watts, darlington

I want to know what is the relation between (100v, 10A) and 100W in darlington transistor or actually any power device like mosfet or bjt transistor

does that means I can use this transistor to drive say 60 volts motor rated 10A ?

would that means that I am consuming 600 w in the motor circuit how would the transistor survive this amount of power

I am confused, I am sure that I am missing something !!

Comment: Besides that you also will need to have an **understanding of electronics** and understanding of what happens when you use a transistor to control a load. The maximum power dissipation of the transistor is **just that** the maximum power dissipation **of the transistor**. It tells you **nothing** about the load.

Comment: I have a basic understanding of electronics but I just want to know the meaning of transistor power dissipation and its relation with the max rated voltage and current

Comment: Well, if you did (with the level of understanding I was implying) then you would not be asking this question ! If you switch a 600 W load on and off with a transistor, where does the 600 W go, into the transistor or in the load ? There are many ways to learn and understand this, on a piece of paper and some hand calculations is a good starting point. In a circuit simulator. On a breadboard with a transistor, some resistors and a LED.

Comment: If you want to become a good electronics engineer (and I highly recommend that you do !) then focus on the **why** instead of the **just knowing**. **Why** is there a max power rating and what does that mean when I switch a load. As opposed to just knowing that it is "the maximum power the transistor can dissipate" without understanding what that means in an application.

Comment: I am software engineer not electrical engineer, what I am trying to do is learn on my own, so it is not that easy, anyway thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does it means 100v, 10A ,100W darlington transistor?

- The maximum voltage that the transistor can withstand between collector and emitter is 100V. Sometimes this spec is between base and collector.
- The maximum current that the transistor can withstand that flows between collector and emitter is 10A.
- The maximum product of current flow and voltage across the transistor is 100 watts.

Current may be allowed to be greater than 10A if applied in short bursts or at a low duty cycle. The same applies to power - it is average power and RMS current that usually kills a transistor. The voltage spec is usually an instantaneous spec.

Comment: The 100 W is the maximum power dissipation depending on the thermal resistance junction to case, junction temperature and operating temperature.

Comment: I expected that answer "that was actually the logical one anyway", I just wanted to make sure of it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you read this in the datasheet that means the transistor absolute maximum rating. Take example for this [N Channel](http://coecsl.ece.illinois.edu/ge423/spring05/group9/IRF520.pdf), if you drive the motor with 10A then you risk to damage the transistor. For the 100W is the maximum power dissipation of the transistor.

Comment: *For the 100W probably is the power dissipation of the transistor* You can safely say that it **is** the maximum power dissipation of the transistor. The datasheet is **about the transistor**. The manufacturer of the transistor **has no idea** about the load you are going to connect. So they mention **what the transistor can handle**. It is up to the user to not exceed that.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I agree with you

Comment: But if you want to dissipate anything like 100W in the transistor, it's going to need a *seriously* good heat sink.

Answer (score 0):

For Muhammad, or anyone else learning EE, Might I suggest ["The Art Of Electronics 3rd edition"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521809266)

Prices vary, but it is THE best reference when learning electronics theory. Also, your question is vague.

A Darlington is a BJT, just internally configured with two BJT's for greater current gain from the base signal. MOSFET's are different animals and VERY static sensitive. 
Choosing components with no safety factor will severely shorten the service live of a given design. If you mean to drive an DC (direct current) motor of 60V@10A then the transistor will dissipate (10A + Ibase) x (Vce drop typ ~4V for darlingtons) = 10A + 20mA x 4V = 10.020A x 4V = 40.08W
At 40.08W you will need an adequate heatsink for the transistor to survive barely! And that would need to be exotic like water cooling. Better to choose a transistor with at least 20A continuous collector current. Your heatsink choices will also broaden and get cheaper.

Choosing components that can handle 2x the design parameters will ensure ruggedness and reliability over a wide temperature range.